# Shift + i (to active bone) for some reason creates a binding to the Root bone

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

Salute! I'm doing a tutorial on rigging. I select 2 arm bones on the rig and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and those bones get snapped to the root bone (my screenshot). This didn't happen in the tutorial and I can't figure out what's wrong. Please tell me who knows!
https://youtu.be/wcU-vTz-lZ0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the <kbd>Chain Length</kbd> on the IK constraint Properties. It's initially set to 0 which means that the root bone is the start of the IK chain. Increase the value until you get the result you want.

[image]

This is explained in the tutorial you're following [here](https://youtu.be/wcU-vTz-lZ0?t=731).